# How do I know what version of scala the maven scala plugin uses?

Tags: scala, maven

I am trying out spring mvc using scala, and the compiler is 2.10.3

I am using another scala library that was built using 2.9 and it giving me an error like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

when I use it in my spring mvc app.  I'm guessing it is because I compiled it with an older version of scala.

I am using the latest scala maven plugin 2.15.3.  When I run mvn package, how do I know which scala compiler version it is using?

I have 2.10.3 installed in /usr/local/opt/scala

Answer (score 1):

Use [scala-maven-plugin](http://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/usage.html), the previous plugin is deprecated:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.6</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Is scala.version a property I have to define or?

Comment: Yes, so for your question `2.10.3`